# Laplacian transform of division by square root of t?

Tags: laplace-transform, harmonic-functions

In this formula:
$$f(t)=e^{-3t}t^{\frac{-1}2}$$
I saw examples on $t^n$ where $n>0$.
But in above example $n<0$.

I don't know how to deal with the $t^{\frac{-1}2}$.

I know that $e^{-3t}=\frac1{s-3}$.

Thanks for helping. 
If I wasn't clear, please tell me.

Answer (score 2):

I am just going to evaluate $L(\sqrt t)$.

Just substitute $\sqrt{st} = x$.

So, $L(\sqrt t) = \int_0^\infty e^{-st} \cdot t^{-1/2} dt$

$= \frac{2}{\sqrt s}\cdot \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} dx  = \frac{2}{\sqrt s} \cdot \frac{\sqrt \pi }{2} = \sqrt {\frac{\pi}{s}}$

Comment: +1, Thanks. But can you explain more on the last step please.